# rspec test for destroy if user doesn't exist

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, factory-bot

I'm using rspec + FactoryGirl for testing my app.

I have the next test

```ruby
context "user cannot be destroyed" do
  before(:each) do
    @user = FactoryGirl.create :user
    delete :destroy, {id: 1}, format: :json
  end
  it "render the json error when the user is not destroyed" do
    user_response = JSON(response.body, symbolize_names: true)
    expect(user_response[:errors][:message]).to include "User cannot be destroyed"
  end
  it {should respond_with 422}
end
```

When I run the test, I get the error `Couldn't find User with 'id'=1` twice. If I change the id `{id: @user.id}` the test doesn't pass and I get the next errors.

```
undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
```

and

```
Expected response to be a 422, but was 204
```

The code I testing is

```ruby
def destroy
  user = User.find(params[:id])

  if user.destroy
    render json: {success: {:message => "User destroyed"} }, status: 204
  else
    render json: {errors: {:message => "User cannot be destroyed"} }, status: 422
  end
end
```

So, I have two questions:

1. How can I fix this?
2. Is necessary to check if the user has been destroyed? (if user.destroy ...)

If the second question is false, I think my life will be easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This part of your test:

```
@user = FactoryGirl.create :user
delete :destroy, {id: 1}, format: :json
```

*assumes* that `@user` will be assigned id `1`.  This is not a safe assumption.  You are correct to change this line to:

```
delete :destroy, {id: @user.id}, format: :json
```

After that change, you say the test fails with:

```
Expected response to be a 422, but was 204
```

Indicating that the user *is* destroyed.

The simplest solution would be to change your controller:

```
def destroy
  user = User.find(params[:id])
  render json: {errors: {:message => "User cannot be destroyed"} }, status: 422
end
```

In the real world, perhaps there are situations where a user *can* be destroyed, in which case you'd need some logic in your controller.

Comment: This solution will be just for to pass the test?

Comment: Maybe a little late, but the test are passing when I do this. Thanks!